# Ring Glow Animation in Android

Tags: android, xml, animation

I'm trying to reproduce [this animation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AndreiD/Kraken/master/ring_glow_animation.gif) from an iOS app in Android. and I'm stuck

If anyone knows how to create them will be deeply grateful. Don't mind the logo in the center, just those rings pulsating. (is possible 3 at a time, short break, repeat)

### Here's a possible solution, but it's quite ugly and I'm sure something nicer can be made

#### 3 imageviews one on top of eachother

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >


  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView_circle1"
      android:layout_width="20dp"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle"
      />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView_circle2"
      android:layout_width="20dp"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle"
      />

  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView_circle3"
      android:layout_width="20dp"
      android:layout_height="20dp"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/circle"
      />


  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imageView_logo"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:scaleType="fitCenter"

      app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo"
      />

</RelativeLayout>
```

#### a drawable circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

  <solid android:color="#DDDDDD"/>

</shape>
```

#### an animation zoom_and_fade.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:fillAfter="false">


  <alpha
      android:duration="3500"
      android:fromAlpha="1.0"
      android:toAlpha="0.0" />


  <scale
      android:duration="3500"
      android:fromXScale="0"
      android:fromYScale="0"
      android:pivotX="50%"
      android:pivotY="50%"
      android:toXScale="50"
      android:toYScale="50" />

</set>
```

#### on Activity:

```
    imageView_circle1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_circle1);
    imageView_circle2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_circle2);
    imageView_circle3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_circle3);

    anim1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoom_and_fade);
    anim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoom_and_fade);
    anim3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoom_and_fade);
    anim2.setStartOffset(800);
    anim3.setStartOffset(1600);

    imageView_circle1.startAnimation(anim1);
    imageView_circle2.startAnimation(anim2);
    imageView_circle3.startAnimation(anim3);

    anim2.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
      @Override public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

      }

      @Override public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

        imageView_circle1.startAnimation(anim1);
        imageView_circle2.startAnimation(anim2);
        imageView_circle3.startAnimation(anim3);
      }

      @Override public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

      }
    });
```

Comment: You might be able to do something like that with a RippleDrawable

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can achieve same result with only XML.
This is really rough code (Literally 5 minutes) using canvas. But I think with some minor changes you can get really nice Animation.
Check out the video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=378Jjc4amD8.
I'll improve if you like it.

```
public class CircleAnimationView extends View {

private Paint[] paints = new Paint[3];
private int[] colors = new int[3];

private float[] circleRadius = new float[3];

public CircleAnimationView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

public CircleAnimationView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

private void init() {

    colors[0] = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.gray1);
    colors[1] = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.gray2);
    colors[2] = ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.color.gray3);

    for (int i = 0; i < paints.length; i++) {
        paints[i] = new Paint();
        paints[i].setAntiAlias(true);
        paints[i].setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paints[i].setColor(colors[i]);
    }


}

public void startCircleAnimation() {
    CircleRadiusAnimation animation = new CircleRadiusAnimation();
    animation.setDuration(1500);
    animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
    startAnimation(animation);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, circleRadius[0], paints[0]);
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, circleRadius[1], paints[1]);
    canvas.drawCircle(getWidth() / 2, getHeight() / 2, circleRadius[2], paints[2]);
}

private class CircleRadiusAnimation extends Animation {

    public CircleRadiusAnimation() {
        setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                reset();
            }
        });
    }

    public void reset() {
        circleRadius[0] = 0;
        circleRadius[1] = 0;
        circleRadius[2] = 0;
        CircleAnimationView.this.requestLayout();
        CircleAnimationView.this.invalidate();
    }


    @Override
    protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation transformation) {
        circleRadius[0] += 10;

        if (interpolatedTime > 0.3) {
            circleRadius[1] += 10;
            Log.d("animate", "2nd circle");
        }

        if (interpolatedTime > 0.6) {
            circleRadius[2] += 10;
            Log.d("animate", "3nd circle");
        }

        CircleAnimationView.this.requestLayout();
        CircleAnimationView.this.invalidate();
    }

}
}}
```